# Printing the output from pseduocode that is using static scoping and nested subroutines

Tags: static, pseudocode, scoping

I found this same question asked on here, but the person formatted the code incorrectly and it affected the answers given.
Here is the code:

```
procedure main
   g : integer
   procedure B(a : integer)
      x : integer
      procedure A(n : integer)
         g := n
      procedure R(m : integer)
         write integer(x)
         x /:= 2 – – integer division
         if x > 1
            R(m + 1)
         else
            A(m)
      – – body of B
      x := a × a
      R(1)
   – – body of main
   B(3)
   write integer(g)
```

I think it should print: 9 4 2 3

I wrote a quick program in C (because it uses static scoping) that did everything the pseudocode does and it agreed with my solution. I have, however, found resources online that point towards the answer of: 9 4 2 1 4

Can anyone explain why that would be the correct answer, or if my answer is correct?